# error in finalizing workflow when tuning recipe

Tags: r, tidymodels

I am creating a random forest model using also umap for dimensionality reduction (tuning both of them). When I finalize the workflow, something appears as missing (probably due to the umap recipe tuning), causing an error:

> Error in structure(list(...), class = c(paste0(.prefix, subclass), "step")) :
> argument is missing, with no default

```
library(tidyverse)
library(tidymodels)
library(embed)

tidymodels_prefer()

df <- iris   

splits <- initial_split(df, strata = Species, prop = 4/5)
df_train <- training(splits)
df_test  <- testing(splits)


df_rec <- 
  recipe(Species ~ ., data = df_train) %>%
  step_umap (
    all_numeric_predictors(),
    num_comp = 3,
    outcome = "Species",
    min_dist  = tune())


rf_mod <- 
  rand_forest( trees = tune() ) %>% 
  set_engine("ranger") %>% 
  set_mode("classification")


df_wflow <- 
  workflow() %>%
  add_model(rf_mod) %>%
  add_recipe(df_rec) 

rf_grid <- grid_regular(trees(), min_dist(), levels = 2)

df_folds <- vfold_cv(df_train, v = 2) 

keep_pred <-  control_resamples(save_pred = TRUE, save_workflow = TRUE)

rf_res <- 
  df_wflow %>% 
  tune_grid(
    resamples = df_folds,
    grid = rf_grid,
    metrics = metric_set(accuracy),
    control = keep_pred
  )

best_rf <- rf_res %>%
  select_best("accuracy")

final_wf <-
  df_wflow %>%
  finalize_workflow(best_rf)
```

Comment: It looks to me like you have uncovered a bug in embed of some kind. I know this is annoying but thank you for the report! I have [opened an issue here](https://github.com/tidymodels/embed/issues/116) if you would like to track it.

Comment: @JuliaSilge, thank you so much for your support (and all the inspiring work)!